# 文字を入力しても出力が表示されない

Tags: c

入力された文字から空白、タブ、改行の個数をカウントするプログラムを作ったのですが、実行後文字を入力しても何も表示されません。。
どこに原因があるのでしょうか。#includeは省きます)

```
int main() {

int c, blank_count,tab_count,row_count;
blank_count = tab_count = row_count = 0;

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (c == ' ') {
      blank_count++;
    }   
    if (c == '\t') {
      tab_count++;
    }   
    if (c == '\n') {
      row_count++;
    }   
  }
  printf("blank: %d\n tab: %d\n row:%d\n",blank_count,tab_count,row_count);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: 「#includeは省きます」とありますが、通常記載のようなコードでは#includeは1行のみのはずです。わざわざコメントを入れてまで省略するより、すべての#includeを記載してください。一緒に#includeされている内容がコードの実行結果に影響を及ぼす可能性はいくらでもあります。また標準入出力は実行環境によって、全く異なる接続先につながりますから、「実行後文字を入力して」では何をしたのかがよくわかりません。「どんな環境でどのように実行してどんな入力を行なったのか」具体的にご記載ください。こちらのテストでは`EOF`が送られるような操作をすれば期待通りの出力が得られたので、環境を含めて実行方法の問題と思われます。またコードを掲載される場合は(ご自身で)コードとして書式を整えてください。編集画面内でコード全体を選択状態にして`{}`アイコンをクリックするだけです。

Comment: BLUEPIXYさんの言われた通り、EOFの入力をしていなかったことが原因でした、OOPerさんもアドバイス有難う御座いました。

Comment: 解決できたのであれば何よりでした。問題の内容によっては、しっかり中身を明らかにする努力を怠ると、見当違いの推定回答が解答欄を埋め尽くして本来の解決の妨げになると言うことがよく見られます。私のアドバイスを少しでもご参考にしていただければ幸いです。なお、今回のBLUEPIXYさんのご回答があなたの問題を解決したのであれば、「承認」の操作をお願いします。過去のご質問にも承認操作をされたのもが見当たりませんが、回答の中でその質問の解決に最も役立ったものを「承認」すると言うのが、このサイトのお約束です。時間を取って過去質問の方も見直して見てください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

提示のプログラムは`EOF`が入力されるまで文字入力を繰り返すようになっています（つまり結果が表示されないのは単に入力待ちになっていると思われます）ので、
`EOF`を入力するなどの必要があります。

例えばwindows環境では<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>(コントロールキーを押しながらＺキーを入力）します。この組合せによる入力が`EOF`入力になります。
(UNIX系環境では<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>)

また、標準入力を対象としているので、
パイプによる入力
windows系での例
`type file.txt | program`
(UNIX: `cat file.txt | ./program`)

リダイレクトによる入力
windows系での例
`program < file.txt`
(UNIX: `./program < file.txt`)

などとすると自らタイプして試す必要はないです。
（そういうテスト入力用のファイルを作成しておくと良いと思います。）

ＩＤＥ環境・オンラインコンパイラ環境などの場合は、
標準入力指定などは異なりますので
その場合は、そのような使用環境などを質問に追記して下さい。

Comment: 有難うございます！
EOFの入力を行ったら期待していた動きになりました！
ご丁寧な解説非常にありがたいです！